# Using the value of state before updating state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Do I need to ignore a missing dependency warning here or is this structured incorrectly?

This component updates a list of products for the supplied personId. The initial product load is via the useEffect with personId as a dependency. However, the product load can also be triggered by a user event (a button click) so the loading functions have been moved out to functions in useCallback.

The linter is correctly warning that loadProductDetails has a dependency on the (state value) productDetail. It uses it to determine what new products it needs to get details for. Including that in the dependency list would trigger an endless loop. loadProductDetails makes use of the current state value of productDetail in a check which products to update - the API call is expensive so only new product details should be fetched after the initial load.

Is the only solution to ignore the linter warning or is there another more effecient pattern. In any solution it must be possible for loadProducts and loadProductDetails to be triggered by a change to the personId prop and the button click (and loadProductDetails should always only fetch new products)

```js
export default function MyComponent({personId}){

    const [products,setProducts] = useState([])
    const [productDetail, setProductDetail] = useState([])

    const loadProductDetails = useCallback((someproducts) => {
        let newProductIDs = getNewProductIDs(someproducts,productDetail)
        CallProductDetailAPI(newProductIDs).then( (data) => {
            setProductDetail([...productDetail, data])
        })
    },[])

    const loadProductsForPerson = useCallback(() =>{
        CallProductAPIForPerson(personId).then( (productData) => {
            setProducts(productData)
            loadProductDetails(productData)
        })
    },[personId,loadProductDetails])

    useEffect( ()=>{
        loadProductsForPerson()
    },[loadProductsForPerson])

    const handleRefreshButtonClick = () => loadProductsForPerson()

    const getNewProductIDs = (products,productDetail) =>{
        //check which product details we already have and then return the new ones to fetch
    }

    return(
        <>
        <div>{products}</div><button onClick={()=>handleRefreshButtonClick()}>Refresh</button>
        </>
    )
}

const CallProductDetailAPI = () => {}

const CallProductAPIForPerson = () => {}
```

Comment: Ok, well one of the approaches is to move out all this caching logic to a separate class and another one - to use useRef hook. You have 2 state variables, add 2 more useRef states for them, (productsRef, productDetailsRef) add 2 more useEffects hooks to update useRef variables respectively, use those useRef variables instead of state ones in your useCallback functions. That way you will be able to get rid of state variables inside depsArray of useCallbacks.

Comment: Thanks! Got you on the caching but wondering how to solve it just in component to make sure I wasn't abusing hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up Sergey's comments and just in case anyone else has a similar issue - this is how I implemented it without the dependency on state. Using refs to hold the previous state. Not sure if it's over-written to avoid a dependency warning that could be ignored but.....

```
export default function MyComponent({personId}){
    const productRef = useRef([]);
    const [products,setProducts] = useState([])
    const [productDetail, setProductDetail] = useState([])

    const loadProductDetails = useCallback((someproducts) => {
        let newProductIDs = getNewProductIDs(someproducts,productRef.current)
        CallProductDetailAPI(newProductIDs).then( (data) => {
            let newDetails = [...productRef.current, data]
            setProductDetail(newDetails)
            productRef.current = newDetails 
        })
    },[productDetail])

    const loadProductsForPerson = useCallback(() =>{
        CallProductAPIForPerson(personId).then( (productData) => {
            setProducts(productData)
            loadProductDetails(productData)
        })
    },[personId,loadProductDetails])

    useEffect( ()=>{
        loadProductsForPerson()
    },[loadProductsForPerson])

    const handleRefreshButtonClick = () => loadProductsForPerson()

    const getNewProductIDs = (products,productDetail) =>{
        //check which product details we already have and then return the new ones to fetch
    }

    return(
        <>
        <div>{products}</div><button onClick={()=>handleRefreshButtonClick()}>Refresh</button>
        </>
    )
}

const CallProductDetailAPI = () => {}

const CallProductAPIForPerson = () => {}
```